# Match character using regular expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to read a document line by line and am interested in only certain characters that are letters, not a new line character.

I have the following:

```
@chars = split //;

for $char (@chars) {
  if (   ($pos % 16569 == 1719)
      || ($pos % 16569 == 8251)
      || ($pos % 16569 == 10238)) {
    print FILE_OUT "$char\n";
  }

  if ($char == m/[A-Z]/) {
    $pos++;
  }

}
```

The regular expression `m/[A-Z]/` fails to match as `$pos` never increases. Is it even possible to match an individual char in Perl, or is this operation only allowed for strings? If so, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean `=~` instead of `==`. `==` is the numeric comparison for equality. `=~` invokes regular pattern matching on the left-hand side of the operator.

Oh, and you should also always `use strict` and `use warnings`, especially in examples.

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes that's right. Weird syntax, it's similar to ~= which means != in Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

There may be more elegant ways of doing this, but the problem you're encountering is that you're using the wrong operator.  `==` means "numeric, is equal to"; in this case, you're asking if $char matches the match of `$_` to your regex (which isn't what you want!)

Instead, you should use the regex match operator: `=~`.